# How will I make this program take scanner inputs until it is commanded by me to stop taking them

Tags: java

Look, I have pasted the whole code for you will understand the problem only when you see the whole code. Coming to my problem I want this program to take he strings until I want It to stop

Look i tried many loops thought upon it for hours and i would be glad if you help me in this issue

```
import java.util.*;
class secretopencoding
{
        public static void main()
        {
                 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.println("Enter a string");
                 String a = sc.nextLine();
                 int l = a.length();
                 int i;
                 char b;
                 for (i=0;i<l;i++)
                 {
                         b = a.charAt(i);
                         if (b=='a'||b=='A')
                             System.out.print("01");
                         if (b=='b'||b=='B')
                             System.out.print("02");
                         if (b=='c'||b=='C')
                             System.out.print("03");
                         if (b=='d'||b=='D')
                             System.out.print("04");
                         if (b=='e'||b=='E')
                             System.out.print("05");
                         if (b=='f'||b=='F')
                             System.out.print("06");
                         if (b=='g'||b=='G')
                             System.out.print("07");
                         if (b=='h'||b=='H')
                             System.out.print("08");
                         if (b=='i'||b=='I')
                             System.out.print("09");
                         if (b=='j'||b=='J')
                             System.out.print("10");
                         if (b=='k'||b=='K')
                             System.out.print("11");
                         if (b=='l'||b=='L')
                             System.out.print("12");
                         if (b=='m'||b=='M')
                             System.out.print("13");
                         if (b=='n'||b=='N')
                             System.out.print("14");
                         if (b=='o'||b=='O')
                             System.out.print("15");
                         if (b=='p'||b=='P')
                             System.out.print("16");
                         if (b=='q'||b=='Q')
                             System.out.print("17");
                         if (b=='r'||b=='R')
                             System.out.print("18");
                         if (b=='s'||b=='S')
                             System.out.print("19");
                         if (b=='t'||b=='T')
                             System.out.print("20");
                         if (b=='u'||b=='U')
                             System.out.print("21");
                         if (b=='v'||b=='V')
                             System.out.print("22");
                         if (b=='w'||b=='W')
                             System.out.print("23");
                         if (b=='x'||b=='X')
                             System.out.print("24");
                         if (b=='y'||b=='Y')
                             System.out.print("25");
                         if (b=='z'||b=='Z')
                             System.out.print("26");
                         if (b==' ')
                              System.out.print("27");
                 }
         }
 }
```

every time It will ask me If i Want to enter the program and continue the lop of running till enter no  continue till i enter no

Comment: The full code is not coming i want to know why

Comment: currently your program reads a line and stop, do you want to read lines multiple times until you want to stop?

Comment: You want to repeat the action until commanded to stop. You can repeat an action with a *loop*. You can stop repeating the action by breaking out of the loop. One way to loop is with a `do-while` statement, which will run at least once. You can break out of the loop either by failing its condition or explicitly calling `break`.

Comment: Not part of the question but you should look of a `case` structure in Java.  This is a prime use case for it, as well as look up `Character.toLowerCase(char)`.  Though you could make this code a lot shorter if you make a `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate what you already have until user stop it. To do that you can use a `while` to iterate, and to stop it you can **set a key** that if it is introduced as input it will stop the program. Then the condition to stop the `while` loop will be that `input.equals(stopKey)`.

I have commented the new lines

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        // key that indicates the program to stop
        String stopKey = "stop";
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        while (!(a = sc.nextLine()).equals(stopKey)) { // when input is equal to key, it stops
            // nothing changed here ...
            int l = a.length();
            int i;
            char b;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                b = a.charAt(i);
                if (b == 'a' || b == 'A')
                    System.out.print("01");
                if (b == 'b' || b == 'B')
                    System.out.print("02");
                if (b == 'c' || b == 'C')
                    System.out.print("03");
                if (b == 'd' || b == 'D')
                    System.out.print("04");
                if (b == 'e' || b == 'E')
                    System.out.print("05");
                if (b == 'f' || b == 'F')
                    System.out.print("06");
                if (b == 'g' || b == 'G')
                    System.out.print("07");
                if (b == 'h' || b == 'H')
                    System.out.print("08");
                if (b == 'i' || b == 'I')
                    System.out.print("09");
                if (b == 'j' || b == 'J')
                    System.out.print("10");
                if (b == 'k' || b == 'K')
                    System.out.print("11");
                if (b == 'l' || b == 'L')
                    System.out.print("12");
                if (b == 'm' || b == 'M')
                    System.out.print("13");
                if (b == 'n' || b == 'N')
                    System.out.print("14");
                if (b == 'o' || b == 'O')
                    System.out.print("15");
                if (b == 'p' || b == 'P')
                    System.out.print("16");
                if (b == 'q' || b == 'Q')
                    System.out.print("17");
                if (b == 'r' || b == 'R')
                    System.out.print("18");
                if (b == 's' || b == 'S')
                    System.out.print("19");
                if (b == 't' || b == 'T')
                    System.out.print("20");
                if (b == 'u' || b == 'U')
                    System.out.print("21");
                if (b == 'v' || b == 'V')
                    System.out.print("22");
                if (b == 'w' || b == 'W')
                    System.out.print("23");
                if (b == 'x' || b == 'X')
                    System.out.print("24");
                if (b == 'y' || b == 'Y')
                    System.out.print("25");
                if (b == 'z' || b == 'Z')
                    System.out.print("26");
                if (b == ' ')
                    System.out.print("27");
            }
            // ask for a new input
            System.out.println("\nEnter a string");
        }
        // at this point user have enter the stop key 
        System.out.println("Stoped. Bye!");
        // close the Scanner
        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: @ShaurryaBaheti nice!, if it helps, consider to vote this answer ;)